# ThreadLocalSessionContext: Current session context does not extend class CurrentSessionContext

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

When using ThreadLocalSessionContext I get this exception: "Current session context does not extend class CurrentSessionContext." upon call to CurrentSessionContext.HasBind.
When switching to `CurrentSessionContext<ThreadStaticSessionContext>()` in my fluent configuration everything works fine.
I am running inside console application with following packages:

```
<packages>
  <package id="FluentNHibernate" version="1.4.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Iesi.Collections" version="4.0.1.4000" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="NHibernate" version="4.0.0.4000" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Please clarify what your question is.

Comment: My question is why I get exception when using ThreadLocalSessionContext .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThreadLocalSessionContext is not compatible with CurrentSessionContext. It has its own methods for binding session, and doesn't work in the exact same way as the others.

Comment: So there is a problem with Fluent configuration, because its signature is `public FluentConfiguration CurrentSessionContext<TSessionContext>() where TSessionContext : ICurrentSessionContext` ? If it is not compatible then how it implements the same interface?

Comment: ThreadLocalSessionContext is not compatible with the static methods in CurrentSessionContext. Use a different context, or use the corresponding methods on ThreadLocalSessionContext.